# ¿Cómo leer un json desde una url con java?

Tags: java, json, netbeans

Tengo este código y quiero leer este `json` que me da la url he intentado de varias maneras recurro aquí por ayuda

```
    private void setInsertarTemperaturaXCiudad(String codigoCiudad)
  {
    logger.debug("setInsertarTemperaturaXCiudad:" + codigoCiudad);

    URL url;
    try
    {    
        url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=" + codigoCiudad + "&units=metric&APPID=(apikey)");

        JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl(url);
//        logger.debug(json);

        JSONObject jsonTemp = (JSONObject)json.get("temp");
        Object temp = jsonTemp.get("temp");
        logger.debug(jsonTemp);

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Este es el json que me entrega la url

```
{

"coord": {
    "lon": -70.65,
    "lat": -33.46
},
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 802,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "nubes dispersas",
        "icon": "03d"
    }
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
    "temp": 27.38,
    "pressure": 1014,
    "humidity": 18,
    "temp_min": 26.11,
    "temp_max": 28
},
"visibility": 10000,
"wind": {
    "speed": 3.6,
    "deg": 190
},
"clouds": {
    "all": 40
},
"dt": 1572983567,
"sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 8506,
    "country": "CL",
    "sunrise": 1572946757,
    "sunset": 1572995583
},
"timezone": -10800,
"id": 3871336,
"name": "Santiago",
"cod": 200
```

}

Comment: Pon el json para saber como es

Comment: Listo, ese es el json que me entrega la url

Comment: Necesitas usar HttpURLConnection para hacer la solicitud HTTP, ahi solo estas creando la URL

Comment: Y como seria la manera correcta de hacerlo, he visto algunos ejemplos en internet de HttpURLConnection pero no me queda claro de como implementarlo, soy nuevo la verdad con json y haciendo llamadas url

Comment: ¿Por qué no pruebas con una biblioteca hecha para eso? [UniREST](http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/#responses)